# Grid View Empty Data Template in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Grid View Which populates data when user clicks on search button. If user have not clicked on search button it should show message no data found in selection. I have done the following:

```
 <asp:gridview id="gvSoag" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  cssClass="table table-hover"
                    AllowPaging="True" EmptyDataText="No Data found in selection.">
                    <emptydatatemplate><asp:Label Text="No Data found in selection." runat="server"></asp:Label></emptydatatemplate> 
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="alert-danger"/>                             
                    <Columns>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub Item Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label ID="gvLbSubItemName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SA_Dscr")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sequence">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label ID="gvLbSequence" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sequence")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allow">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Image ID="gvLbAllow" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("isSelected")) == false ? ("Not Allowed") : ("Allowed") %>' src='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("isSelected")) == false ? ("images/redAF.png") : ("images/greenAF.png") %>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" Style="padding-right: 4px;  vertical-align: middle;"
                                        runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' AlternateText="Edit" ImageUrl="images/setting.gif"
                                        OnClick="imgEdit_Click" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Edit"/>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" Style="padding-right: 4px;  vertical-align: middle;"
                                        runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="images/delete.gif"
                                        OnClick="imgDelete_Click" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Delete"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerSettings Visible="False" />

                  </asp:gridview>
```

If user selects some dropdowns than it shows message if empty result found. How can I get this to be done that when user comes at very first time it should show some message some thing like please select option search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EmptyDataTemplate doesn't work unless you've done a DataBind.

you can do:

```
gridview1.DataSource= new [] {};  
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thankyou I have done this at page load :) `if (gvSoag.Rows.Count < 1)
                    gvSoag.DataSource = null;
                    gvSoag.DataBind();`